# Get all metadata schemas of a publication

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am quite new to Tridion core service so this might be a simple question. I want to get all metadata schemas by passing a publication ID. If some one has ever done this please reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried already? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

There are tons of examples of using the Core Service to retrieve items from Tridion both on Stack Overflow and on the interwebs in general. Try some of them and see how they map to your needs. If you get stuck doing that, we will do our best to get you "unstuck".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, here is an example. GetCoreServiceClient returns a SessionAwareCoreServiceClient with Impersonate already called for the correct user.

```
public static IdentifiableObjectData[] GetMetadataSchemas(string publicationId)
{
    using (var client = GetCoreServiceClient())
    {
        var filter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData
        {
            SchemaPurposes = new[] { SchemaPurpose.Metadata },
            Recursive = true,
            ShowNewItems = false,
            ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Schema }
        };

        return client.GetList(publicationId, filter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I will suggest you to look sample code from [here][1](Login required) and try your self first.

[http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_95D8F90693834AF089FEBCDC0347D04D][1]

or try this.

```
RepositoryItemsFilterData filterData = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
filterData.ItemTypes = new[]
                       {
                        ItemType.Schema
                       };
filterData.Recursive = true;
XElement resultXml = client.GetListXml(publicationId, filterData);
```

And then you need to create each schema object after getting ids from above xml and check whether it is metadata schema.